# It doesn't print the label "etiqueta_2" again in the window I've created with tkinter (only print once)

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the function I've created to print "You've clicked".

```
    etiqueta_2=Label(ventana, text ="You've clicked").place(x=500, y=300).pack()
```

And this is the button I've created to make the function "frase" work.

```
boton.configure(command=frase)
boton.place(height= 50, width=100, x=455, y=500, anchor=CENTER)
```

AND THIS IS THE ERROR:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'
```

The problem: It only prints in the window I've created "You've clicked" ONE TIME when i click the buttom. Only 1 time.      WHY?????   ;) (please, explain to me the error in order not do do it again)

Comment: It is meaningless to call both `.place()` and `.pack()` on the same widget.  (And `.place()` returns None, so you're actually trying to call `.pack()` on None rather than the widget.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of:

```
etiqueta_2=Label(ventana, text ="You've clicked").place(x=500, y=300).pack()
```

use this:

```
etiqueta_2=Label(ventana, text ="You've clicked")
etiqueta_2.place(x=500, y=300)
etiqueta_2.pack()
```

When you call a function the function return statement will return a variable. Every function return a variable, if the return statement isn't used the function will return None.

The function/method `.place()` that you call return None, and you cannot call `.pack()` function/method because None doesn't have any.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! So is always etiqueta_2.place() and etiqueta_2.pack() instead of these methods together? With every type of data (images, labels, buttoms, etc.)?

Comment: yep. please mark the correct answer for future readers